# Many to Many relation between two tables

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to create a relational database in which there are two tables Users and products. Each item of each table can be related to many items of the second table.

My current implementation is as follows:

Two main tables-

```
->Users
User ID
UserInfo

->Products
Product ID 
ProductInfo
```

Two different lookuptables

```
->UserToProduct
UserID
ProductID

->ProductToUSer
ProductID 
UserID
```

Each time a relation from a user to a product is added, i just add an extra row to the first lookup table, and vice versa.

Is this the right way to do it? Are there any standard models for such scenarios that I can refer to?

Comment: Maybe you just need one table USER-PRODUCT with an extra row for the direction of the relationship?

Comment: @Gowtham Since you think you need to have two tables, can you describe your use case? I **know** that you only need one table for the join, but I **think** you need/want to track additional metadata that is relevant to the relationship. I just have no idea what that additional metadata is.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Simple use case - I want to search how Products User A has. I use the first table. Second case, I want to see how many users bought Product A, so I search the second table.

Comment: @Gowtham You don't need two tables for that use case; you just need to write appropriate queries. To clarify, your problem is not really one of creating data (Insert/Update) as it is one of reading data (Select).

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Final comment - would it be better to use a single table with a direction indicator or two different tables keeping performance in mind?

Comment: @Gowtham I would use a single join table with metadata. Simply indicating a direction is not likely to be very useful or descriptive. Instead I would use something more meaningful to indicate the nature of relationship, similar to how Amazon can track both the products I've purchased from Amazon as well as the products I've told Amazon I already own when it makes a recommendation to me. In both cases the direction of the relationship is the same (User owns Product), but the metadata (source of ownership) is different.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Thanks for all the help. Will implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two lookup tables, all you need is `users_products`.  As far as resources, there are zillions, just google *"database many to many"*.

**UPDATE**

Consider this data:

```
products
------------
id     info
------------
1      car
2      flute
3      football

users
------------
id     info
------------
10     bob
20     tim
30     manning
```

Now, as a simple example, let's say *manning* owns a football and and a car.  Let's say *tim* owns a flute and a football.  Now here's your lookup table:

```
users_products
----------------------
user_id    product_id
----------------------
  20           2
  20           3
  30           3
  30           1
```

That's it.  Now you can do queries like "give me all the users that have cars", or "give me all the cars that a user has", etc.

Cheers

Comment: That's what I thought, but I think he wants 2 individual relations?

Comment: @Madbreaks Could you please clarify? If I have only one lookup table, how would I know which type of item is related to which other type of item?

Comment: @ChristianVarga I want bidrectional many-to-many relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Your relationships are users-to-products, which is an `n-to-n` relationship.  That only requires one table to join on.  One user may have many products, one product may belong to many users.  Use a small data set and fill out the users_products table...it will start to make sense.

Comment: The way I read his question: one product may not only _belong_ to many users, but it may also _have_ many users. Why would a product _have_ users?

Comment: @ChristianVarga You're confused man.  Just hang back, please.  Your comments are only making this more difficult, no offense intended.

Comment: @ChristianVarga Why is the distinction relevant?

Comment: Sorry for dragging this simple question further, I just wanted my cncepts clear. If I have only one lookup table, without any additional direction indicator, how will I figure out which way the relation is defined? I must add here that the product and user ids come from the same set of language, so they might not be unique with respect to each other

Comment: I took the examples of Users and Products as an example to illustrate my question. They have no real world significance.

Comment: You can add additional columns to your join table to define metadata that is relevant to the relationship, but it's not clear to me how/why the direction of the definition is relevant, hence why I asked in another comment for a use case.

Comment: No, I'm not confused at all, and the question is directed at the OP, not you. The distinction matters because that's how the question is worded. I think he wants to have _unique_ relations between both tables. Eg, the Users that a product _belongs_ to might be different from the list of products that the user _has_. And your answer doesn't differentiate the relationship.

Comment: @ChristianVarga You got my point exactly. I thought I made it clear in the question. Apparently I did not. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @ChristianVarga Try directing your comments toward someone.  Without you saying otherwise, a comment under my answer means the comment is directed at me.

Comment: @Madbreaks Let's say a `football` has a `tim`, but `tim` doesn't have a `football`. That's the difference between `has_many` and `belongs_to`. Stupid example because of the context, but you get the idea.

Comment: @ChristianVarga has_many and belongs_to are used to describe 1-to-n relationships from either the parent (has_many) or child (belongs_to) side of the relationship. Nonetheless, they describe the same relationship. I agree with Madbreaks that you're not clarifying the discussion.

Comment: @Madbreaks Just because a Product is related to the user does not mean the user is related to the product. I probably threw you off because I used the words user and product. Anyways I got the concept now. Upvotes for everyone who participated in the discussion. And I chose Madbreaks answer as the right one because he gave an example

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Exactly. They describe the same relationship when one is used on one model, and the other is used on the other model. So if _both_  models have _both_ `has_many` and `belongs to`, there should be 2 sets of relationships going on.

Comment: 2 unique sets. A relates B does not imply B relates to A in my case.

Comment: `A relates B does not imply B relates to A in my case.` @Gowtham Then you don't really have an m-to-n relationship IMO.

Comment: @ChristianVarga I know that's how ActiveRecord works, but that's not how database modeling works. Sorry.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll being condescending doesn't help the problem. If that's not how database modelling works, then provide an answer _that solves the ops problem_ instead of _arguing against my points_. I was the only one who understood the problem, and in return for trying to point out how _you guys_ didn't understand it, I get condescending remarks like "you're confused" and "that's not how it works".

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need or want two different lookup tables. You should just have one (either of your tables, UserToProduct or ProductToUser, would be fine). The primary key of the lookup table should be a composite key consisting of both ProductID and UserID.

Comment: Saw your answer after I posted mine... clearly you're the quicker typist :)

Comment: What exactly is a composite key? @sbyd way of using an extra column to signify the direction of relationship sounds great.

Comment: A composite key is one that consists of multiple columns. I'm still confused as to why you think you need two tables to join on.